# [PlayFramework 2.5][Java] JSON post request binding into form

Tags: java, json, forms, rest, playframework

My controller is for REST service and should receive JSON :

```
body {
  "text": "string",
  "page": 0
}
```

I created class according to this:

```
@ApiModel(
        value="FSearch",
        description = "Parameters for user search"

)
public class FSearch {

@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "Text , to lookup for",
    notes = "Can be empty",
    required = false
)
 public String text;

 @ApiModelProperty(
    value = "Page number of search results",
     required = true
 )
 @Constraints.Required
 public int page;

}
```

My controller bidning looks like this:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result search(){
 Form<FSearch> searching = formFactory.form(FSearch.class).bindFromRequest();
 if (searching .hasErrors()) {
      return badRequest(searching .errorsAsJson());
 }
  //Another not releated code
  return ok(Json.toJson(result));
}
```

Now when I test with sending data like this:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ "text": "bla", \ "lol": 0 \ }'
```

So I am sending this JSON:

```
body {
  "text": "bla",
  "lol": 0
}
```

Notice lol instead of page, but form is still binded without any errors...
What should I do to ensure that variable names match in json binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *very* poorly documented, but the `Required` annotation is [essentially not much more than a `null`-check](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.12/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.java#L105). Since an `int` will never be `null`, it will therefor always pass. Either make the field an `Integer` (which can be `null`), or use one of the number based constraints like `Min` to check if its a valid value other than the default (assuming that there is a number that can be marked as invalid, like a negative one or something).